# Python: Initializing class inside source code causes NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm a python noobie still learning the ropes

Initializing GroupBy(_GroupBy) is causing my code to give a
NameError: name '_get_grouper' is not defined

```
class GroupBy(_GroupBy):
    def _add_numeric_operations(cls):        
        cls.first = GroupBy(_GroupBy).nth(-1, dropna=False)
```

_get_grouper is called in the init for _GroupBy

```
class _GroupBy(PandasObject, SelectionMixin):
    def __init__(self, obj, keys=None, axis=0, level=None,
        grouper=None, exclusions=None, selection=None, as_index=True,
        sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=False, **kwargs):
        if grouper is None:

            grouper, exclusions, obj = _get_grouper(obj, keys,
                                                    axis=axis,
                                                    level=level,
                                                    sort=sort,
                                                  mutated=self.mutated)
```

---

```
class Grouper(object):
    def _get_grouper(self, obj, validate=True):
        self._set_grouper(obj)
        self.grouper, exclusions, self.obj = _get_grouper(self.obj, [self.key],
                                                      axis=self.axis,
                                                      level=self.level,
                                                      sort=self.sort,
                                                      validate=validate)
        return self.binner, self.grouper, self.obj
```

The nth method functions if I call it in the python command line, but initializing its class inside the source code raises this error. What am I missing?

Comment: Why should `Grouper._get_grouper` be visible inside `_GroupBy`?

Answer (score 0):

You called `_get_grouper()` in itself and in `__init__` of class `_GroupBy`.

First, you'd better remove that recursive call.
Generally, you can make an another implementation to replace a recursive call

In `__init__` of class `_GroupBy`, replace `_get_grouper()` with `Grouper._get_grouper()`, to clarify that which class has `_get_grouper()`

These make solve the problem.